# Proper way to remove components/tasks from yeoman/grunt?

Tags: gruntjs, yeoman, bower

I'm new to the Yeoman/Grunt/Bower stack and I'm unsure if there is a proper way to remove a component/task from my project.  I don't use CoffeeScript (which was packaged with the Yeoman generator) and it **feels** like I should be using a Grunt task or Bower command to remove the files/requirements/config/etc.

However, I can't find anything mentioning how to do this.  Am I missing something or should I just remove the components by hand?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I don't believe there is an automated way of doing this; save for https://github.com/indieisaconcept/grunt-plugin but that's for the old release (0.3.9) of Grunt.

For Grunt tasks, simply remove the line in `devDependencies` in `package.json` and then remove the relevant section in `grunt.initConfig` and you will have uninstalled the plugin. Depending on how your Gruntfile looks, you may have to remove the `grunt.loadNpmTasks(<package>)` section for the relevant plugin. Then remove the directory in `node_modules` (or run `npm uninstall <package>`). Simple really.

Bower is even easier; remove the relevant line in `bower.json` and delete the directory it was installed (the default is `bower_components`).

Hope this helps. :)

Answer (score 4):

You can remove a Grunt task by running the following command:

```
npm uninstall grunt-task-name --save
```

...where `grunt-task-name` is the name of the task you want to remove. The `--save` flag tells npm to update your package.json file as well as deleting the relevant package from your node_modules directory. (nb. if the task is listed under `devDependencies` - as it might well be - you might need to use the `--save-dev` flag instead).

For Bower the process is the same, only with `bower uninstall` instead of `npm uninstall` (as mentioned in [Michael Onikienko's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19914189/proper-way-to-remove-components-tasks-from-yeoman-grunt#answer-27818031))

Answer (score 1):

For Bower components:

```
bower uninstall componentName --save
```

This command will uninstall component from `bower.json` and from `bower_components` folder.